# How to delete the Article info (Joomla 3.0)?

Tags: joomla, joomla-article

As the title of question, I want delete all info in a Joomla article (ex :author, create date, print icon, ...) .When I create an article, it will show default . I try to hide it, but it only hide and Joomla still create the empty  tag of info . Here, you can see :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please avoid to customize the core Joomla files like article or other.If You want to change or customize the article default file (like you say the article info) by using the template overridden method.for more details go the link below:

[How to override the output from the Joomla! core](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)

Comment: @Lodder As he said that he had tried to hide the information with the parameters but Joomla still create the empty tag of info.That's why i suggest him to try it with template overridden.

Comment: ah ok fair enough. might be an idea to let the OP know which files have to be overridden.

Comment: The path for the which have to overridden is `components\com_content\views\article\tmpl\default.php`

Comment: Thanks, but I want know what I need edit to delete Article header ?

Comment: @user1833554 That's i have mentioned in my answer just edit the article `default.php` with template overridden method.